# Recommendations for fitting nonlinear vector function in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

I am new to tensorflow, so sorry if the following code is not very intelligent. I would like to ask you for recommendations while fitting/training a neural network. A minimal working example is given below, m-dimensional vectors `x` with real valued entries are the input (features, if I understand correctly the terminology), while the outputs (labels, I think) are n-dimensional vectors `f(x)`.

For the upcoming example (in python 3.6.5), let's use 2d vectors `x` (m=2) and 2d vectors `f` (n=2), at what I am approximating a square root function (first component of `f`) and a sinus function (second component).

**What would you recommend me to do, in order to improve the model? Are there any rules of thumb?**

Later I need to deal with high dimensional input x and high dimensional output f(x), but first I want to know how to do better in small examples like the following.

I have been playing around with different numbers of neurons, number of layers, activation functions, optimizers, step sizes and number of epochs. Any recommendations? I already standardized / normalized the inputs x and outputs f, i.e., I computed their means and stardard deviations and rescaled x and f accordingly.

---

**Example in python 3.6.5:**

I will need these modules

```
#%% Setup

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import tensorflow as tf
```

The following lines generate some input data x (x1 from 0 to 8 and x2 from 0 to 15, each direction is discretized in 30 points) and compute the exact values of the functions f(x), and display the functions f1(x) and f2(x)

```
#%% Generate data

lx = (8,15)
nx = 30

x = np.array(np.meshgrid(*[l*np.linspace(0,1,nx) for l in lx])).reshape(len(lx),-1).T
f = np.array([[10*np.sqrt(sum(xx)), 10*np.sin(np.sum(xx))+20] for xx in list(x)])

dx = np.shape(x)[1]
df = np.shape(f)[1]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,2))
fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection='3d').scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],f[:,0])
fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, projection='3d').scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],f[:,1])
```

[image: plots of f1 and f2]

The following lines standardize / nomalize the input and output data and plot again the data (check that x and f have been rescaled)

```
#%% Standardize data

def sdata(x):
    for i in range(np.shape(x)[1]):
        x[:,i] = (x[:,i]-np.mean(x[:,i]))/np.std(x[:,i])
    return x

x = sdata(x)
f = sdata(f)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,2))
fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection='3d').scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],f[:,0])
fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, projection='3d').scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],f[:,1])
```

[image: x and f rescaled]

The following lines are the setup for the neural network. You can change or add number in the number of neuros `nn`. The length of the tuple `nn` automatically defines the number of layers. The activation function is `af`, the opimizer `opt` and the number of epochs `nep`.

```
#%% Neural network setup

# Number of neurons in layers, activation function, optimizer and number of epochs
nn = (16,16,16,df)
af = tf.tanh
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01)
nep = 3000

# Placeholders for input x, output f
xp = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,dx])
fp = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,df])
# Build sequential model, last call is output
model = xp
for i in range(len(nn)-1):
    model = tf.layers.dense(model,nn[i],activation=af)
model = tf.layers.dense(model,nn[-1],activation=None)
# Loss function (MSE), training step and initializer
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(model-fp))
trainstep = opt.minimize(loss)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

The following lines start the tensorflow session, plot the initial prediction values `fpre(x)` (of f(x)), compute the values of the loss function (mean square error, MSE), do the training, plot the loss function over the epochs, plot the final predicition of f(x) and plot the absolute difference between the output data f(x) and fpred(x)

```
#%% Session, train, see results

# Start session
s = tf.Session()
s.run(init)
# Plot predicted values before training at positions x
fpre = s.run(model,{xp:x})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,2))
p1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection='3d')
p1.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],f[:,0])
p1.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],fpre[:,0])
p2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, projection='3d')
p2.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],f[:,1])
p2.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],fpre[:,1])
# Prepare container for loss data and print initial loss
lossd = [None]*(nep+1)
lossd[0] = s.run(loss,{xp:x,fp:f})
print(lossd[0])
# Train
for i in range(1,nep+1):
    s.run(trainstep,{xp:x,fp:f})
    lossd[i] = s.run(loss,{xp:x,fp:f})
# See loss development
print('Last loss:\n'+str(lossd[-1]))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(list(range(nep+1)),lossd)
# Plot predicted values after training at positions x
fpre = s.run(model,{xp:x})
print('Computed MSE:\n'+str(np.mean((fpre-f)**2)))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,2))
p1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection='3d')
p1.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],f[:,0])
p1.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],fpre[:,0])
p2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, projection='3d')
p2.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],f[:,1])
p2.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],fpre[:,1])
# Plot difference
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,2))
p1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection='3d')
p1.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],np.abs(f[:,0]-fpre[:,0]))
p2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, projection='3d')
p2.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],np.abs(f[:,1]-fpre[:,1]))
# Close sessions
s.close()
```

This was the initial prediction

[image]

This is the loss function over the epochs

[image]

This are the final predictions and the absolute difference

[image]

Any thoughts on how to improve this or make the code more efficient? Thank you!

Comment: Your code looks fine and visualization is great. If I read your code correctly, in each epoch, you run through all your data points. So essentially you have a batch_size=900. I think you can utilize mini-batch. In each step, you can make a batch_size = 100 (for example), which is a slice of your entire data. This should help you more (trains much faster) when you have significantly more datapoints.

Comment: yes, in each epoch I run through all the data. So batch slicing reduces the number of prescribed values in the loss function, right? And therefore the optimization should run faster, although I imagine that it will not necessarily be as accurate as with the full data set. I dont know how batch slicing works, sorry.